# Python Data Frame resample on micro second

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I am working with resampling data frame and it works on hours, days mins, but doesn't resample less then sec. Program just hangs even on short time span. So am I missing something?

I tried 0.000001S, U etc... Nothing worked so far.

my time format:    2015-08-29 19:30:47.015506

you can see varable sf represent resampling freq.

```
grph = df.set_index('Date and Time').resample(sf, len).astype(int)
```

How can I resample data frame on micro seconds granularity?

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example?  The first thing to to check is that your `index` contains actual datetimes and not just strings.

Comment: What do you mean by reproducible example? And my index ["Date and Time"] is type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, I set it by df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[2])

Comment: "Reproducible example" means something that other people can copy and paste so they can see the same problem you're seeing.  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on MCVEs.

Answer (score 17):

```
sf = "1U" #for one microsecond
```

For milliseconds/microseconds/seconds use:

```
L       milliseonds
U       microseconds
S       seconds
```

[Full doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
B       business day frequency
C       custom business day frequency (experimental)
D       calendar day frequency
W       weekly frequency
M       month end frequency
BM      business month end frequency
CBM     custom business month end frequency
MS      month start frequency
BMS     business month start frequency
CBMS    custom business month start frequency
Q       quarter end frequency
BQ      business quarter endfrequency
QS      quarter start frequency
BQS     business quarter start frequency
A       year end frequency
BA      business year end frequency
AS      year start frequency
BAS     business year start frequency
BH      business hour frequency
H       hourly frequency
T       minutely frequency
S       secondly frequency
L       milliseonds
U       microseconds
N       nanoseconds
```

Comment: Do you have a link to that doc?

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly you can't resample microseconds to another frequency that is less than a second, right? I made a toy example and there doesn't seem to be a problem though:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
index=pd.date_range('22/10/2010', periods=100000, freq='U')
example=pd.Series(index=index,data=np.random.randn(100000))
example.resample('ms',how='sum')
```

This gives the expected output.

(I think your problem is that you are trying to resample data that are in a microsecond format to microseconds itself, which doesn't make any sense. You want to either upsample or downsample (as in my example).)

Comment: I manage to fix it (I need to set really short time span), but it is so much time even on msec. Is there a way to speed up the process?

Comment: To see where most of the time is going to, a starting point could be to do some profiling by running  `%prun -l 10 example.resample('ms',how='sum')`.

Comment: The `how` attribute is deprecated since version 0.18.0 in pandas, use like this `example.resample('ms').sum()`. refer : [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas-series-resample)